# Как при создании объектов использовать условие Python

Tags: python, django

Есть условие перед записью в БД

```
        if data['data']['category']['id'] == '5297':
            catid= 2
        elif data['data']['category']['id'] == '5298':
            catid = 3
        elif data['data']['category']['id'] == '5299':
            catid = 4
     
        else:
            catid=None
```

Записываю в БД вот так:

```
News.objects.create(                    
                image=new_preview_img_url,                    
                category=NewsCategory.objects.get(id=catid), 
                body=new_body,
            )
```

Мне нужно в случае, когда catid == None

Записать в category None.
Как-то примерно так:

```
News.objects.create(                    
                image=new_preview_img_url,                    
                     if catid is not None:
                        category=NewsCategory.objects.get(id=catid),
                     else:
                        category = None,
                body=new_body,
            )
```

Но так не выходит, так синтаксически вообще возможно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно:

```
News.objects.create(                    
                image=new_preview_img_url,                  
                category=NewsCategory.objects.get(id=catid) if catid is not None else None,
                body=new_body,
            )
```

То есть:

```
...
category=NewsCategory.objects.get(id=catid) if catid is not None else None
...
```

Или так:

```
...
category=NewsCategory.objects.get(id=catid) if (catid is not None) else None
...
```

Comment: Получается, что просто не надо было использовать двоеточие после if?)

Comment: @АндрейИванов Надо было переписать `if` на тернарную версию, которую можно подставлять куда угодно, да )